# How to use Material UI date picker with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, datepicker, dayjs

Look, Im not one to just put 'any' as the type when i dont know what to do, but i must say, i am seriously getting frustrated here. I am using Material UI date picker along side the DayJS date library.

This is the example material UI have on their website:

[image]

On the example above, they are clearly using the Dayjs type which dayjs provides, which is also what i use in my function below:

```
const BookingComponent = () => {
    const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState<Dayjs | null>(null)
    return (
        <div className='flex justify-center'>
            <Stack spacing={4} sx={{ width: '280px' }}>
            <DatePicker
                label='Select a Date'
                format='DD-MM-YYYY'
                value={selectedDate}
                onChange={newValue => {setSelectedDate(newValue)}}    
            />
            <button onClick={() => console.log(selectedDate)}>click</button>
            </Stack>
        </div>
    )
}

export default BookingComponent
```

When i log 'selectedDate' out into the console, this is what it looks like:

[image]

As you can see from the picture above, '$d' is holding the date information that i need. So i try to console it out by typing 'console.log(selectedDate.$d)' but then i get this error:

```
Property '$d' does not exist on type 'Dayjs'
```

So i actually do not understand, I obviously dont just want to put 'any' as the type and move on but if it doesnt exist on type 'Dayjs' then what type does it exist on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$d` is an implementation detail (what would be a private property in a more traditionally object-oriented language); there aren't type definitions for it because you aren't intended to use it directly. You can instead use the documented [`toDate` method](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/as-javascript-date) (e.g., `selectedDate.toDate()`).

Comment: thank you, it solved my problem by putting selectedDate(dayjs(newValue).toDate())